# It says my Python requests library and get function are not being used?

Tags: python

disclaimer- noob here!

i keep running into the issue that says I imported requests but am not using it. not sure how to proceed.  I looked in my package library and it is there under site-packages, however I do not see the 'get' function in it. I am using PyCharm, and have also checked this Spyder.  Same problem

```
import json
import requests

from requests import get as geturl 

url = 'http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json'
response = geturl(url)
print(response)
result = json.loads(response.text)
print(result('iss_position'))
```

Comment: Yeah, you're not using the name `requests` in your code after you've imported it. What's the problem?

Comment: You're using `geturl`, not `get` or `requests.get`... What don't you understand?

Comment: By the way, `response.json()` should be used rather than `json.loads(response.text)`

Comment: `print(result('iss_position'))` will throw an exception as well; `result` is not a callable.

Comment: If it works, why are you worried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> from requests import get as geturl
>>> url = 'http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json'
>>> response = geturl(url)
>>> result = response.json()
>>> print(result)
```

> {'message': 'success', 'iss_position': {'latitude': '-40.8208', 'longitude': '103.2043'}, 'timestamp': 1509893252}

You can either use

```
import requests
requests.get(url, params=None, **kwargs)
```

Or

```
from requests import get as geturl
geturl(url, params=None, **kwargs)
```

You have used both, which is redundent and the `requests` is not being used as `requests.get()` that's was the reason why you were getting that message.

Comment: thanks a lot. i didn't realize that I was calling it twice

Comment: You are welcome, You can upvote and accept as an answer when it satisfies what you have asked.

Comment: Thanks Rajan!  I just accepted it.  What editor do you like to use?

Comment: Editor? Do you mean **IDE**, I do use **PyCharm** and other **Jetbrains** products. I do love their IDE, including WebStorm, PhpStorm, Android Studio, and other. 

You can use sublime if you like, however, choosing an IDE is all up to you.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the name `requests`. You can safely remove the `import requests` line. Your `from requests import get as geturl` line suffices.

As a side note, you can load JSON responses directly without having to import `json`:

```
result = response.json()
```

so all you need is

```
from requests import get as geturl 

url = 'http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json'
response = geturl(url)
result = response.json()
print(result['iss_position'])
```

Comment: I'll just use the opportunity to plug [`response.raise_for_status`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes) :-)